# Is there an easier way of moving items in a list up and down than this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a sorting user interface, where the user can click an up or down button on the list to move an item up or down and store the new order in the database.

The sort order is stored on the property `SortOrder`, which ranges from 1 (top) to the number of items in the list (bottom).

This is the code I use for sorting at the moment:

```
List<Item> items = await db.Items.ToListAsync();
Item item = items.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
if (direction == "up" && item.SortOrder > 1)
{
    Item itemAbove = items.Where(i => i.SortOrder == item.SortOrder - 1).FirstOrDefault();
    item.SortOrder--;
    itemAbove.SortOrder++;
    db.Update(item);
    db.Update(itemAbove);
}
if (direction == "down" && item.SortOrder < items.Count)
{
    Item itemBelow = items.Where(r => r.SortOrder == item.SortOrder + 1).FirstOrDefault();
    item.SortOrder++;
    itemBelow.SortOrder--;
    db.Update(item);
    db.Update(itemBelow);
}
await db.SaveChangesAsync();

// redirect to the list view
```

I'm pretty new to C#, so I was just wondering if there were any handy sorting methods on `List<T>` I could use. Maybe something like

```
items.MoveUp(i => i.SortOrder == 4); // swaps items #3 and #4
```

Comment: Use a List<>(), use InsertAt and Remove()

Comment: "*I was just wondering if there were any handy sorting methods*" the an answer is no, though you do have the power. If you are putting the sort order in a field, there isn't much more you can do other than encapsulate your logic

Comment: There are a few sorting methods out of the box, but none would do what you want. You however have the power to make your own using [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

If you just want to simplify your code, for the need to update multiple data at the same time, you can use **UpdateRange**.

Simplify your code as follow:

```
            List<Item> items = await db.Items.ToListAsync();
            Item item = items.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (direction == "up" && item.SortOrder > 1)
            {
                items.Where(i => i.SortOrder == item.SortOrder - 1).FirstOrDefault().SortOrder++;
                item.SortOrder--; 
            }
            if (direction == "down" && item.SortOrder < items.Count)
            {
                items.Where(i => i.SortOrder == item.SortOrder + 1).FirstOrDefault().SortOrder--;
                item.SortOrder++; 
            }
            db.Items.UpdateRange(items);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your thoughts behind your answer, but why wouldn't I want to avoid using the database? I _want_ the new order to be stored in the database, because the order is used in other places in my application. That is the whole purpose of sorting it.

Comment: @Stian, if so, your current code can fully meet your needs, so what is the purpose of your question?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I could achieve the same result using fewer lines of code.

Comment: @Stian, sorry for misunderstanding , I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OrderBy if you don't mind hard coding the condition.

```
        public class Entry
        {
            public Entry(int sortOrder)
            {
                this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
            }

            public int sortOrder;

        }

            List<Entry> ents = new List<Entry>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ents.Add(new Entry(i));
            }

            ents = ents.OrderBy((x) =>
            {
                if (x.sortOrder == 1)
                    return 5;
                else if (x.sortOrder == 5)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return x.sortOrder;
             }).ToList();

            Debugger.Log(0, "cat", "\r\n" +string.Join(", ", ents.Select(x => x.sortOrder.ToString()).ToArray()) + "\r\n");
```

Output:

> 0, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9